# Is there a way to detect if a filter exists in an image or not?

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm following Andrew Ng's [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuD4C8vJzEQ&ab_channel=Deeplearning.ai) [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=am36dePheDc&ab_channel=Deeplearning.ai) on edge detection and I'm trying to detect if a filter exists in an image.
So if I have 2 images and 2 filters (1 that detects horizontal lines and 1 that detects vertical lines):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

img = np.array([[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0]])
img2 = np.array([[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[10,10,10,0,0,0],[0,0,0,10,10,10],[0,0,0,10,10,10],[0,0,0,10,10,10]])

vertical = np.array([[1,0,-1],[1,0,-1],[1,0,-1]])
horizontal = np.array([[1,1,1], [0,0,0], [-1,-1,-1]])
```

I tried to convolve the filters on each image using

```
print(convolve2d(img, vertical, 'valid'))
[[  0 -30 -30   0]
 [  0 -30 -30   0]
 [  0 -30 -30   0]
 [  0 -30 -30   0]]
print(convolve2d(img, horizontal, 'valid'))
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Is there a way to create a function that will return `1 / 0` if the filter exists or not?
It gets a bit more complex with more complex images like `img2`:

```
print(convolve2d(img2, vertical, 'valid'))
[[  0 -30 -30   0]
 [  0 -10 -10   0]
 [  0  10  10   0]
 [  0  30  30   0]]
print(convolve2d(img2, horizontal, 'valid'))
[[  0   0   0   0]
 [-30 -10  10  30]
 [-30 -10  10  30]
 [  0   0   0   0]]
```

So I was trying to come up with a function that returns a percentage of how much the filter exists, but got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by 'filter exists'?

Comment: For example, in `print(convolve2d(img, horizontal, 'valid'))` you can see that the output is an array of all 0's- showing that the filter (horizontal) does not appear in the image. That is because there are no horizontal lines in the image (img), but only a vertical one

Comment: try `np.any(convolve2d(img, vertical, 'valid'))` to see True/False statements. You may convert them to integers using `int` command.

Comment: Thanks Kate! That works for the first image, but not for the second one. I could also just sum the array and see if it's greater than 0, in a naive approach. But it gets more complex as I mentioned with more complex images (like `print(convolve2d(img2, vertical, 'valid'))`

Comment: The method above should work for all images... Could you please clarify what does not work?

Comment: You can sum absolute values of the array, but `np.any` is more efficient in general... Maybe, you want to discard the small values in the filtered image?

Comment: Yes, definitely! Apologies for the confusion. By not working I mean that `np.any` will output `true` for any array with at least 1 value that is not 0. But in a real-life image with many more pixels there will always be 1 such value. Hence it will always output `true`. Which brings me to my second point, of looking for a function that that returns a percentage of how much the filter exists. Let me know if it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments, we decided to compute the percentage of zeros (or very small values in the matrix). Suppose that the matrix is `arr`. Then,

```
mask = np.where(abs(arr) < 0.00001, 0, 1)
percent_zeros = np.mean(mask)
```

where `0.00001` is the threshold (below this value, we assume that all entries are zeros) and `percent_zeros` outputs the ratio of non-zeros in the array (values between 0 and 1), where 1 means that there are no zeros in the matrix.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant solution! Thanks Kate : )